# Using two routers in one network

Tags: router, wireless-router, home-networking, wireless-access-point

I have a [TP-LINK WR740N](http://www.tp-link.com/en/products/details/?model=TL-WR740N). My neighbor is using my Wi-Fi network but the signal is weak, so now I am trying to connect a second router ([D-Link DIR-615](http://www.dlink.com/bg/bg/home-solutions/connect/routers/dir-615-wireless-n-300-router)) to the network in order to boost the signal better.

I don’t have much knowledge about networks and need some help in order to do this (if it is even possible or makes sense).

What I have done is to connect the second router to the first using two LAN ports. Then I have connected a PC to the second router. The PC seems to have an Internet connection, but the signal is low, so I think I have missed something.

Can anyone help me with the steps I need to perform?

I can configure the routers through Windows 7 or 8 or Ubuntu if that helps.

Comment: similar to: http://superuser.com/questions/659447/modem-firewall-switch-wireless/659464#659464

Answer (score 0):

Connecting the two routers will only make the connection slightly slower, in general.
You could connect a wireless access point to your router or modem with a long ethernet cord and put the access point closer to your neighbor's house, that might make a small difference.
When combining the two routers, you aren't adding any power or bandwidth or anything, you are generally getting the combination of the worst features of both routers, or to put it differently, you are getting the functionality of the slower of the two routers.